# Django LogEntry without user

Tags: django, django-logging

In my app there's a `Project` model which users can create, request to join, invite others to join, accept/reject requests/invites to join, leave, etc.

I'm using the Django `LogEntry` to help the application admins keep track of all changes to each `Project`, but also changes to related objects such as `ProjectMember`, `ProjectMemberRequest` and `ProjectMemberInvite`.
Both `ProjectMemberRequest` and `ProjectMemberInvite` have expiration dates which means that, if they aren't accepted/rejected within 3 days after being created, the system  automatically sets them as 'expired'.

**How can I log this automatic expiration of `ProjectMemberRequest` and `ProjectMemberInvite`, knowing that `LogEntry` requires a user and this expiration actions are not triggered by a user?**

A workaround I could use is to create a "System" superuser and log these automatic actions to that user.
Is there anything better?

Comment: How do you 'automatically' expire those objects?

Comment: With [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/). When a `ProjectMemberRequest`/`ProjectMemberInvite` object is created, it sets a celery task to expire the object 3 days later, in case it isn't accepted in the meantime.

Comment: I think there is no "better" option than using a system user if you would like to use Django Admin's LogEntry module.